# Tensorflow - NotImplemented Error : Negative indices are not supported

Tags: tensorflow

Iam new to Tensorflow. I am trying to build a convnet with the below model. I am getting a NotImplementedError. The code looks fine, not sure what I am missing. Error is in line -> hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2,layer2_biases)

with graph.as_default():

```
tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
tf.float32, shape=(128, 24, 24, 3))
tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(128, 10))

layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5,5,3,64],stddev=0.1))
layer1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))

layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5,5,64,64],stddev=0.1))
layer2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[64]))

layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([6 * 6 * 64 ,384],stddev=0.1))
layer3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[384]))

layer4_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([384,192],stddev=0.1))
layer4_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[192]))

layer5_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([192,10],stddev=0.1))
layer5_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[64]))

def model(data):
    conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(data,layer1_weights,[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
    hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1 + layer1_biases)
    hidden1 = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
    padding='SAME', name='pool1')

    conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(hidden1,layer2_weights,[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
    hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2,layer2_biases)
    hidden2 = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden2,ksize=[1,3,3,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME',name='pool2')
    shape = hidden2.get_shape().as_list()
    hidden2 = tf.reshape(hidden2, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])

    hidden3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden2, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)

    hidden4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden3, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases)
    return tf.matmul(hidden4,layer5_weights) + layer5_biases

logits = model(tf_train_dataset)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,tf_train_labels))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.relu`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#relu) takes two arguments: `features` Tensor and `name` string and you send two tensors. It should be:

```
conv2 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv2, layer2_biases)
hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)
```

[`tf.bias_add`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#relu) is just a special case of `tf.add`.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Instead of adding both the variables i had passed them as arguments.

Comment: Cool! Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.